# Angular sourcing textarea from file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load text file config1100.txt to textarea (on initial page load), see below. Also tried http://localhost:3000/data/config1100.txt (file is avail), no success so far.

```
<p><textarea ng-src="data/config1100.txt" type="text" id="textarea" model="myTextArea" cols="80" rows="10" >

</textarea></p>
```

Comment: you need to actually load the file using `$http.get()`

Comment: `ng-src` is intended to be used with `<image>` tags, when you have dynamic image file names. `<textarea>` doesn't have a `src` attribute, and so using `ng-src` with it will do nothing. Use `$http` as suggested above to fetch the data, store the data in a model, and bind the model to your text area with `ng-model`.

Comment: like below ? can't get it working : var app = angular.module("angularApp", [])
.controller("myConfigGenCtrl", function($scope, customService) {
    $scope.myTextArea = function () {
        customService.getData()
    } ;
    
})
.service ('customService',function($http) {
    this.getData=function() {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url:'http://localhost:3000/data/config1100.txt'})
            .success(function(response){
                response;
            });
    }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this irom:

```
var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);

app.controller("myConfigGenCtrl", function($scope, customService)
{
  customService.getData().then(function(response)
  {
    $scope.myTextArea = response.data; //-- scope.myTextArea is your ng-model on your text area
  });
});

app.service('customService',function($http)
{
  this.getData = function()
  {
    return $http.get('localhost:3000/data/config1100.txt');
  };
});
```

also, your text area attribute `model` should be `ng-model`

Comment: got 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/data/config1100.txt. Cross origin requests are.. ' but I think I will figure it out Thnx